# Is there a way to restrict merging from a specific branch in git?

Tags: git

Hoping there's a way to keep an environment branch (in our case dev, staging, and production) from being merged into a feature branch.

We aren't able to assign dedicated owners to our environment branches, and restricting push access to branches for certain users won't work for us, so solving the problem via a workflow change isn't an option - we really want to stop someone from making a commit based on a merge from an environment branch.

Guessing a solution would involve hooks, but I haven't been able to find a way to make our specific use case work.

Comment: So you are saying that you cannot enforce this from your repo (e.g. GitHub or Bitbucket) ?

Comment: This is going to be hard, because they might rebase your "environment branches" onto a feature branch instead of merging it, so you cant just look for a merge. Even if you did look for a merge, they could merge in and then continue their work by rebranching off from that merge point, so you might think that they have not merged, but would have already happened and there is no way to know about that previous merge since the branch name is only associated with the current head of it, and not past commits (if that makes sense).